# AngularJS .run() causing initial views to not load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have the following setup in my main angular.js file

```
var application = angular.module('application', [...]).config([..., function(...) {

    //Setup routes
    $routeProvider...

}]).

directive('applicationDirective', function() {
    ...
}).

controller('main-controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    ...
}]).

run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    //Empty
}]);
```

At the moment the application consists of two pages, a login page and a dashboard page. The `$routeProvider` is configured to load a specific view and controller for each of these routes in the `$config` directive.

This all works fine without the `.run(...);` function.

When I add the .run(...) function to the end, even though the body is empty it seems that the $routeProvider doesn't run straight away, the initial view doesn't load on either '/dashboard' or '/login' however if I click a link to those pages once it's been opened they work fine.

Does anyone know why it's not loading the view and controller correctly when I use the run block?

Comment: Documentation: Run function has only one parameter - [initializationFn](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/type/angular.Module).
And only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system configuration during application run time.

Comment: Ah thanks, I've changed it to `run(function($rootScope, $location) { ... });` - As per the example I'm following from http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/ but still no cigar

Comment: It now looks like the problem is coming from the $location parameter, $rootScope alone works fine

Comment: $location has a known injection problem - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1417 . In the comments user 'swlasse' has a work around.

Comment: Makes sense that this could be a bug, I found a workaround by including $route (but not actually using it)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in this order:

```js
var application = angular.module('application', [...])
.config([..., function(...) {

    //Setup routes
    $routeProvider...

}])
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    //Empty
}]); 

angular.module('application')
.directive('applicationDirective', function() {
    ...
})
.controller('main-controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    ...
}]);
```

Comment: Exactly the same, it works if I include $route without using it, doesn't work if I don't include $route